# Can't close this form

Tags: c#, winforms

I run a new form

```
static void Main()
       {
           Application.EnableVisualStyles();
           Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
           Application.Run(new FormMain());   
       }
```

Then I call into `FormMain()`:

```
Application.Run(applicationContext);
```

How can I close `FormMain` by code?

Here is `FormMain`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using EasyTabs;

namespace CefSharp
{
    public partial class FormMain : Form
    {
        public static AppContainer Container = new AppContainer();


        public FormMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Container.Tabs.Add(new EasyTabs.TitleBarTab(Container)
            {
                Content = new frmTab
                {
                    Text = "New Tab"
                }
            });
            Container.SelectedTabIndex = 0;
            TitleBarTabsApplicationContext applicationContext = new TitleBarTabsApplicationContext();
            applicationContext.Start(Container);

            Application.Run(applicationContext);

            this.Hide();
            if(Container.ExitOnLastTabClose)
            { 
                this.Close();
            }

        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Just `Close();`, it should be the form that was created at start of the application.

Comment: Unless you are doing something unusual, your program should contain only one `Application.Run()` call.

Comment: We would need to know more about your `applicationContext` variable to help you.

Comment: ```TitleBarTabsApplicationContext applicationContext = new TitleBarTabsApplicationContext();```

Comment: i want to run the applicationContext and i call Application.Run() to do that

Comment: Call `Application.Run(applicationContext);` after the `Application.Run(new FormMain());` line.

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: Can you explain it more to me?

Comment: You haven't given me enough to work with.  So move `TitleBarTabsApplicationContext applicationContext = new TitleBarTabsApplicationContext();` line after the `Application.Run(new FormMain());` line, then call `Application.Run(applicationContext);`

Comment: if i try to close FormMain by ```this.Close()``` then get an Exception : _Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'FormMain'.'_

Comment: You are talking about code I can't see.  Hence, why the question was closed.

Comment: I am just a new member.Sorry about that.My bad

Comment: What's the point of MainForm if you try to hide it before it gets on the screen?  Doesn't look like you need it.

Comment: I have found this solution for my project here. FromMain will help me create a FromTab by code

Comment: At FormTab i call ```FormMain.Container``` and i can manipulate with the Container

Comment: You can always add to your tabs a new tab easily by calling this code on another form ```FormMain.Container.Tabs.Add(new TitleBarTab(FormMain.Container)
            {
                Content = new Form2
                {
                    Text = "Form2"
                }
            });
            FormMain.Container.SelectedTabIndex += 1;```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, it's not that simple as i wrote without checking. I figured out solve with threads use. First we need delegate on form:

```
public delegate void closer();
partial class FormMain {
    public closer Closer;
    (...)
}
```

Inside class constructor or in `InitializeComponents` add `Close` method to it:

```
this.Closer += Close;
```

Create public static FormMain object:

```
static class Program {
    public static FormMain form1;
    (...)
}
```

Then you just run threads with running window and simply (in this case after 5 seconds) close the window:

```
Program.form1 = new FormMain();
Thread fo = new Thread(() => { Application.Run(Program.form1); });
Thread th = new Thread(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); Program.form1.Invoke(form1.Closer); });
fo.Start();
th.Start();
```

Comment: It does not work with me.I still got Exception _'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'FormMain'.'_ when i try to call method `this.Close()`

Comment: Can you need more information? I don't know how to describe it so you can find a solution for me

Comment: This problem is very common. In short: the object is disposed and you should invoke it. That is why in my sample i use `Invoke` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different approaches:

1. As previously mentionded you can use `formMain.Close()`
2. And `Application.Exit()` to totally close the application.

If you want something more special use Bartek solution. But still, the information you gave us are not enough